# Nullable and generics

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

I'm trying to create a generic node class which can hold any number of children nodes, a string for the node key, and a data node which may or may not be null. However, I'm having problems getting the syntax right to have it accept the generic into the generic parameter for Nullable.

```
internal class TrieNode<E>
{
    Nullable<E> Data;
    string Key;
    List<TrieNode<E>> Children;

    public TrieNode(E? data, string key)
    {
        Data = data;
        Key = key;
        Children = new List<TrieNode<E>>();
    }
}
```

On compile time I get the following error messsage:

> The type 'E' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Is there a way to guarantee that E is a non-nullable type, or some other way around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need:

```
internal class TrieNode<E> where E : struct
```

The `: struct` clause limits `E` to value types **excluding `Nullable<>`**, which allows `Nullable<E>` or `E?` to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try  internal class TrieNode where E : struct

I *think* that Nullable types need to be value types rather than reference types (Reference types are already nullable)

Answer (score -2):

Why not just declare the node to use `object`? An object can refer to any data type, and can also be null.